# Whats the best way to bring an already running app to the front in android?

Tags: android

I have two apps that I want to be able to switch between without killing each different activity and without re-launching the activity I want to switch back too.

Lets say I have a edittext in each activity and I want the text that is written to stay in that edittext view so that when this activity is brought to the front again it's still there. 
The problem is that I can't use savedinstancestate, shared preferences or a database to store the information. It should just be there while the application is running. So if it's killed in the background and the info disappears it's no problem.

So what could be the best way of switching between two running applications within these two applications?

André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done this myself.But i think you can achieve this using `android:launchMode` giving something like `singleTop` .here the reference [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)